# Ifthenelse fails if is part of argument

Tags: conditionals, xifthen

I have followed very simple tutorial to create own `listof`. Link is https://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/

It worked great, I just wanted to add optional parameter. If this optional is given, to the custom ToC it will send this optional parametr. But I get error, which I don't understand.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
...
\newcommand{\listTMname}{List of TMs}
\newlistof{TM}{tms}{\listTMname}

\newcommand{\TM}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{TM}
\par\noindent\textbf{TM \theTM. #2}
\addcontentsline{tms}{TM}{\protect\numberline{\theTM}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}%
}\par}
```

I wanted to use it as follows: `\TM{To text and ToC}` and `\TM[to ToC]{To text}` But I get error calling is on line 94:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. l.94 \TM{Test...}

What I did wrong? If in `\addcontentsline...` command I remove ifthenelse and put it into `\textbf` 2 line above it works, but not opposite way.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the whole `\ifthenelse` in braces?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  To good to get useful answers it usually best to collect your code snippets in to  minimal compilable document demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @TeXnician yes I tried, did not help, 
Andrew Swann thanks, next time I will know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\ifthenelse` is fragile and so is the whole construction

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{#1}
```

Use an expandable test, such as

```
\newcommand{\TM}[2][]{%
  \par\noindent
  \refstepcounter{TM}% <--- don't forget %
  \addcontentsline{tms}{TM}{%
    \protect\numberline{\theTM}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax#2\else#1\fi
  }%
  \textbf{TM \theTM. #2}% <--- don't forget %
  \par\nopagebreak
}
```

Alternatively, with `\usepackage{xparse}`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\TM}{om}{%
  \par\noindent
  \refstepcounter{TM}% <--- don't forget %
  \addcontentsline{tms}{TM}{\protect\numberline{\theTM}\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{#1}}%
  \textbf{TM \theTM. #2}% <--- don't forget %
  \par\nopagebreak
}
```

I changed the position of the various items for placing the anchor (in case you use `hyperref`) in the right place.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Glad that you pointed version with and withou package `xparse`